# Determine when cell value is within date range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send an email when cell value is within Date and Date + 7.

My code only works for one condition so it is either Date or before Date or after Date.

There is a Syntax Error in the code below:

```vb
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = Date Or cell.value > Date And < Date + 7 Then
    'the rest of the code...'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the condition for both sides of the And. Also when in doubt use bracketing

```
If cell.Value = Date Or (cell.value > Date And cell.value < Date + 7) Then
'                                              ^
'                                              What is smaller than Date+7?
```